# DHCPOFFER delay VLAN

Tags: linux, cisco, vlan

I have configured two VLANs [ 15 and 16 ] and a trunkport on a Cisco Catalyst 2960. The trunkport is connected to eth2 on a Linux server
The server is configured to support VLAN's and the interfaces eth2.15 eth2.16 is configured with ip addresses on two different subnet.
dhcp3-server is running on the same server and hands out IP-addresses to the VLANs.

When connecting a client to a port that is configured in ex. VLAN 15 and requesting a IP-address, i experience a long delay
before recieving a DHCPOFFER, around 30 seconds or so, the client needs to send a DHCPDISCOVER about five times but will
always recieve a DHCPOFFER.

Any suggestion why this delay is happening?

Answer (score 3):

maybe enabling port fast will solve your problem.

http://tips-made-easy.info/computer/tips52/Cisco_CCNP_Certification__BCMSN_Exam_Tutorial__Uplinkfast.html

Comment: I have now checked and spanning-tree portfast is disabled on all VLANs but the delay is still present..

Comment: you need to enable port fast!!!!!!!!

Comment: Depending on the switch in some cases you really do need to enable portfast even though STP is disabled on the VLAN's in question.

Comment: @john883: DONT EVER DISABLE STP. It is too easy to create a loop and then your network is down. STP in its basic default config should cause no problems. Enable port-fast on individual ports like they said.

Comment: @einstien +1 , you should never disable STP unless you know what you are doing. Layer 2 loops are nasty and can cause your network to become useless.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be a DNS issue. Perform a tcpdump on the DHCP server to confirm.

tcpdump -i  -lennvs0 port 53

As the DHCP server produces a lease it may be performing a DNS lookup for the IP address it's about to hand out, so that it can include a host name record in the DHCP offer.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing to do is use `tcpdump`/`tshark` to see where the delay is.

```
tshark -i eth2.15
```

Then connect a client and try to get a DHCP lease.

Another thing to do would be to plug a dumb switch in between, wait a minute or so and plug a client in to that, if it comes right up then STP related delays are almost certain.

On the client end running `dhclient` at a console (ideally without `network-manager` or similar so you can be sure that the system isn't doing it automatically) prints every packet it sends or receives, that's a great way to confirm if packets are getting dropped by the switch.